# Polars Dataframe: Apply MinMaxScaler to a column with condition

Tags: python-polars

I am trying to perform the following operation in Polars.
For value in column B which is below 80 will be scaled between 1 and 4, where as for anything above 80, will be set as 5.

```py
df_pandas = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
        "B": [50, 300, 80, 12, 105, 78, 66, 42, 61.5, 35],
    }
)

test_scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(1,4)) # from sklearn.preprocessing
df_pandas.loc[df_pandas['B']<80, 'Test'] = test_scaler.fit_transform(df_pandas.loc[df_pandas['B']<80, "B"].values.reshape(-1,1))
df_pandas = df_pandas.fillna(5)
```

This is what I did with Polars:

```py
# dt is a dictionary
dt = df.filter(
    pl.col('B')<80
    ).to_dict(as_series=False)
below_80 = list(dt.keys())
dt_scale = list(
    test_scaler.fit_transform(
        np.array(dt['B']).reshape(-1,1)
    ).reshape(-1) # reshape back to one dimensional
)

# reassign to dictionary dt
dt['B'] = dt_scale
dt_scale_df = pl.DataFrame(dt)
dt_scale_df
dummy = df.join(
    dt_scale_df, how="left", on="A"
    ).fill_null(5)
dummy = dummy.rename({"B_right": "Test"})
```

Result:

| A | B | Test |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50.0 | 2.727273 |
| 2 | 300.0 | 5.000000 |
| 3 | 80.0 | 5.000000 |
| 4 | 12.0 | 1.000000 |
| 5 | 105.0 | 5.000000 |
| 6 | 78.0 | 4.000000 |
| 7 | 66.0 | 3.454545 |
| 8 | 42.0 | 2.363636 |
| 9 | 61.5 | 3.250000 |
| 10 | 35.0 | 2.045455 |

Is there a better approach for this?

Answer (score 4):

Alright, I have got 3 examples for you that should help you from which the last should be preferred.

Because you only want to apply your scaler to a part of a column, we should ensure we only send that part of the data to the scaler. This can be done by:

- window function over a partition
- partition_by
- when -> then -> otherwise + min_max expression

### Window function over partititon

This requires a python function that will be applied over the partitions. In the function itself we then have to check in which partition we are and deal with it accordingly.

```py
df = pl.from_pandas(df_pandas)
min_max_sc = MinMaxScaler((1, 4))

def my_scaler(s: pl.Series) -> pl.Series:
    if s.len() > 0 and s[0] > 80:
        out = (s * 0 + 5)
    else:
        out = pl.Series(min_max_sc.fit_transform(s.to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)).flatten())
        
    # ensure all types are the same
    return out.cast(pl.Float64)

df.with_column(
    pl.col("B").apply(my_scaler).over(pl.col("B") < 80).alias("Test")
)
```

### partition_by

This partitions the the original dataframe to a dictionary holding the different partitions. We then only modify the partitions as needed.

```py
parts = (df
         .with_column((pl.col("B") < 80).alias("part"))
         .partition_by("part", as_dict=True)
)

parts[True] = parts[True].with_column(
    pl.col("B").map(
        lambda s: pl.Series(min_max_sc.fit_transform(s.to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)).flatten())
    ).alias("Test")
)

parts[False] = parts[False].with_column(
    pl.lit(5.0).alias("Test")
)

pl.concat([df for df in parts.values()]).select(pl.all().exclude("part"))
```

### when -> then -> otherwise + min_max expression

This one I like best. We can make function that creates a polars expression that is the `min_max` scaling function you need. This will have best performance.

```py
def min_max_scaler(col: str, predicate: pl.Expr):
    x = pl.col(col)
    x_min = x.filter(predicate).min()
    x_max = x.filter(predicate).max()
    
    # * 3 + 1 to set scale between 1 - 4
    return (x - x_min) / (x_max - x_min) * 3 + 1

predicate = pl.col("B") < 80

df.with_column(
    pl.when(predicate)
    .then(min_max_scaler("B", predicate))
    .otherwise(5).alias("Test")
)
```